# change iframe content jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'd like to change my iframe content but I don't understand how

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="frame" width="100%" height="95%" src="http://google.com"></iframe>
    <script type=text/javascript >
        $('#frame').contents().find( "body" ).html('<p>hi</p>')
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

With this code I always have my google page and not a ifram with hi

Comment: You can't, you don't have access to cross origin domains in an iframe due to the same-origin policy, and if that weren't enough Google uses x-frame-options and can't be framed.

Comment: there is an exemple with jquery https://api.jquery.com/contents/ but it doesn't works for me, a ok I understand because the request is from jquery, is there a solution to change ifram content ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){        
       $('#frame').on('load', function() {
           $(this).contents().find( "body" ).html('<p>hi</p>');
       });
  });
</script>
```

While this is right, the content will never change as you are trying to modify the body of an external resource. You cannot do this due to cross-site scripting rules.

**EDIT:**

The only way to do it is to do what @user1153551 did and replace the whole document.

Answer (score 5):

Check this [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5Lmn/)

you have to use load event within the iframe's document and calling out to a load function in the containing document to replace to a body contain.

#### jQuery

```
$('#frame').load(function() {
  $('#frame').replaceWith('<p>hi</p>');
});
```

#### HTML

```
<iframe id="frame" width="100%" height="95%" src="http://w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

Use **[.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)** jQuery Method.

Comment: Yes this is the only way to do it, by replacing the WHOLE document with your content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this was not my goal

Comment: Your jsFiddle does not seem to change the content of the iframe

Answer (score -1):

use **[document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)**

```
<script type=text/javascript >
  $(document).ready(function(){        
      $('#frame').on('load', function() {
       $(this).contents().find( "body" ).html('<p>hi</p>');
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Cause the answer is wrong, there's no need for a DOM ready handler as the script tag comes after the element in the DOM.

Comment: Both wrong. you need a handler to see if the iframe has completely loaded. At the point of execution the iframe will be in a "non-ready" state (probably still doing the DNS fetch). You need to catch the iframe load event.. see my answer